# How to Implement Hotspots in Google Webdesigner's 3D Swirl Component?

Tags: 3d, components, banner, web-frontend, google-web-designer

I'm attempting to use Google Web Designer's 3D Swirl Component to display an interactive rotating phone in an ad. I want to implement "hotspots" so that when the phone hits a certain point in it's rotation, arrow and caption graphics can pop-up to explain certain features of the phone, and then disappear when the hotspot rotation "range" is passed.

The current online build guides only explain how to set up the most basic example of Swirl, with rotation on page scroll and click and drag, and only mention "hotspots" in passing. So far I haven't been able to find any examples, explanations, or advanced build guides for this topic.

When I look inside the GWD component I don't see any reference to "hotspots" and when I add "events" the closest thing I can see is "Hotspot clicked" or under "Camera changed" I see "Look at Hotspot". Both are unclear to their purpose..

Can someone please point me in the right direction, or provide an example where hotspots are being used for this purpose?

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @Cmaxster - Wondering if you were able to implement the hotspots. I'm in the same boat. Not much documentation around this feature.

Comment: Hi @Jammy. It's been a while since I worked on this project and it got shelved before I was able to begin, so my memory is a bit fuzzy now. I vaguely remember that there were 2 different versions of Poly. There was a general purpose one, and a developer centric one that had more features. When I spoke with Google they said it was still in Beta, so even they didn't have much info. I also remember the hotspots were very templated, not a lot of customization options available.

Comment: @Jammy - I found it! https://poly.google.com/pro You have to put "pro" at the end of the URL I think... very strange that they don't have this documented better. I also heard that Poly was being discontinued later this year, so keep an eye out for that too.